# Passing struct to function pointer - Value changes

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linux-kernel, function-pointers

I'm working on a kernel thread which uses a struct as function argument.

I passed it like this

```
   int thread_function(void* data)
{
    struct killStruct* obj = (struct killStruct*) data;
    //msleep((unsigned int) time);
    printk(KERN_INFO"From the inner Thread: PID: %d, Time:%ld\n",obj->pid,obj->millisecondsToKill);
    //kill prozess by ID
    return 0;
}

static void prozess_kill(struct killStruct *obj)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Outside of thread PID: %d, Time:%ld",obj->pid,obj->millisecondsToKill);
    task = kthread_run(&thread_function,(void*)obj ,"str");
}
```

For some strange reason the value of pid is different outside of the thread than inside the thread.

In fact it logs:

```
[12160.460200] Outside of thread PID: 1, Time:1000
[12160.460400] From the inner Thread: PID: 622736, Time:1000
```

What is happening here?

Note: I checked other values for pid. It always ends up as 622736

Comment: In C there's no need to cast pointers to `void *`. Any pointer can implicitly be converted to `void *`.

Comment: How do you call `prozess_kill`? What is the lifetime of the `killStruct` object?

Comment: Maybe modified by other process. Try to malloc some memory and copy the data and pass it into "thread_function" to see the difference.

Comment: Ok I did something stupid... I freed the struct to early - so in fact @JoachimPileborg solved it! Thanks!

Comment: From a debugging point of view you should print the value of the pointer address to confirm whether you are printing info from the same structure. If it is confirmed then some code must have changed the structure `pid` field before `thread_function` gets executed. Hence @JoachimPileborg's comment.

Comment: @ChristopheAugier That would not matter, as the actual pointer is copied (passed by value) and won't change even when it's freed from another thread.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg of course, it was just to confirm all assumptions and make sure that he was reading its structure at the same memory address. For some unknown reason `kthread_run` may have corrupted the pointer address before running `thread_function`. The fact that the value of the time was the same suggested that it was the same but didn't prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question and if somebody rans into the same problem:

I jfreed the struct outside of the thread. For some reason the freeing was executed before the reference was inside the function. This caused the strange error and I solved it by placing the kfree in another position.